# What does "process system isn't responding. do you want to close it?" means?

Tags: eclipse, emulation, android-virtual-device

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4JBa.jpg)

Yesterday, I just ignore this.
I clicked "OK". Actually, I had no problems doing my work.

But, i want to know what this means.

Can I just ignore this like what I did yesterday?

or, Should I take an action to prevent further errors?

Comment: check here https://ageeky.com/process-system-not-responding-fix/

Comment: does this also work for emulator?